# Php post form without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I try to post my form to Mysql without refreshing page. I did these with looiking sources but not working. Could you help me?

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            message: '*I couldnt find this partwhat should i write*'
        }
        }               
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post">
<textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="30">
</textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Submit.php

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $post = $_POST['message'];
    $date = date("y-m-d G:i:s"); 

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat_messages SET senderid = ?, receiverid = ?, message = ?, mod_time = ?"); 
    $insert = $query->execute(array( $a, $b, $post, $date));
}?>
```

Comment: This `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` prevents the saving . you know right?

Comment: your submit has no id

Comment: a simple look at your developer console, would have thrown you something about it

Comment: Syntax Error on javascript  inside Script tag, One Extra `}` hope this is not the reason

Comment: @Rajan that would be "one" issue, yes.

Comment: There are soo many issues here. Syntax errors too. Maybe a PHP AJAX tutorial isn't a bad idea

Comment: why did you go and stealth edit the post and defacing the original? you didn't comment or anything. You went and used code from answers. I am rolling it back

Comment: Thank you. You are really helpful. I did changes according to your suggestions but I could not work these codes.

Comment: @Can please clarify. What is still not working? Did you give the `id` attribute to your submit `input` tag? **AND**, did you remove the extraneous brace?

Comment: @Rushikumar Yes i did '<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">'  Do i need to write any code like "onclick" in submit button

Comment: @Can in addition to that, you also need to remove `}`... please re-check my answer, as I clarified that part

Comment: @Rushikumar I check everyone suggestion but i couldn't. Could you check this link i posted my code https://jsfiddle.net/476Lkqm4/

Comment: @Can, JSFiddle will not parse your PHP code... Also, I have re-updated my answer with some more clarification.

Comment: @Rushikumar Yes it works :) Thank you very much for your interest my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting form data through Ajax query, hence you do not need to include `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`  in your `submit.php` file.

```
<form>
<textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission action
            $.post("submit.php", $("form").serialize()); // Post the data
            $('textarea[name=message]').val(''); // Clear the textarea
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, are the variables `$a` and `$b` defined in `submit.php` file?

Comment: If you have questions, please post them under OP's question as a comment...

Comment: That requires at least 50 reputations. I do not have that.

Comment: @FaisalAlam After i click, the message still in the messsage box. Is it possible to remove after click submit

Comment: Yes, sure! Add one more line of javascript code after `$.post`.
`$('textarea[name=message]').val('')`
Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, the `click` event is being triggered on an element that has an id of *submit* (it is **id** because it is represented by **#**)

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
```

Your submit button does not have the ID of "submit"

Change the `input` tag as follows:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Another problem, as @Rajan in comments pointed out, you have an extra brace. So, change:

```
data: {
    message: '*I couldnt find this partwhat should i write*'
}
}
```

to:

```
data: {
    message: '*I couldnt find this partwhat should i write*'
}
```

Also, I recommend that you show return some kind of message from `submit.php` page, for example:

```
echo 'Entry Added';
```

The above is just an example output to get you going... you really should be doing checks such as: did the entry get inserted without any errors, etc.

#### Edit

Also note: you are using `type` as one of the settings. Per the official jQuery documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `type` is:

> An alias for **method**. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

(i.e. use `method` instead, if using jQuery version >1.9.0)

Lastly, take a look at the answer provided by @Faisal as well...

Comment: you missed something; being a stray brace

Comment: actually, Rajan caught it [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212019/php-post-form-without-refresh-page#comment83405401_48212019)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.post('../submit.php',{message:message}, function(data) {
      
      $('.results').html(data);
   });
```

use a div where you want to display the result

```html
<div class="results"></div>
```

to finish your submit.php have to send something at the end so try this

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $post = $_POST['message'];
    $date = date("y-m-d G:i:s"); 

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat_messages SET senderid = ?, receiverid = ?, message = ?, mod_time = ?"); 
    $insert = $query->execute(array( $a, $b, $post, $date));
}
echo "it works";
?>
```